# How to make NavigationStack work with Views and popToRoot in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationstack

I'm trying to use NavigationStack with Views in SwiftUI, but I'm having trouble understanding its functionality. I have gone through several tutorials, but I still don't understand the purpose of the `value` parameter and why all the tutorials use `ForEach` to create subviews instead of linking actual views.

In my case, I’m just trying to make the following code work and go back to the ContentView() when I press the “Go to ContentView” button, but nothing happens and the rootPath.count remains at 0:

```swift
-----------------ContentView-----------------
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var path = NavigationPath()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path) {
            Image(systemName: "figure.fall")
                .imageScale(.large)         .foregroundStyle(.tint)
            NavigationLink("Go to FirstView") {
                FirstView(rootPath: $path)
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

------------------FirstView------------------
struct FirstView: View {
    @Binding var rootPath: NavigationPath
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink("Go to SecondView") {
            SecondView(rootPath: $rootPath)
        }
    }
}

-----------------SecondView------------------
struct SecondView: View {
    @Binding var rootPath: NavigationPath
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink("Go to ThirdView") {
            ThirdView(rootPath: $rootPath)
        }
    }
}

------------------ThirdView------------------
struct ThirdView: View {
    @Binding var rootPath: NavigationPath
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("RootPath: \(rootPath.count)")
        Button(action: {
            rootPath = NavigationPath()
        }, label: {
            Text("Go to ContentView")
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Each view you want to put on the stack (first, second, third) should have an associated value, which can be anything that is Hashable. Making a new type for it might be a bit clearer for what you are trying to do here. For example:

```
enum Destination: Hashable { case first, second, third }
```

You associate the value to the view when `navigationDestination` gets called. The root view doesn't need a value.

2. The path is just a representation of the stack as a collection of values (which represent views). Don't use `NavigationPath` type (it's only for cases where your view value types can be different), instead almost always just an array will do. You update the path by NavigationLink or alternatively just assigning/appending/removing something to it directly. The path is on top of the root, so making it empty gets you back all the way.

```
var path: [Destination] = []`
```

Here's your code modified with the points above, it might clarify things a bit.

```
class PathState: ObservableObject {
  enum Destination: String, Hashable {
    case first,second,third
  }
  @Published var path: [Destination] = []
}

//-----------------ContentView-----------------
struct ContentView: View {
  @StateObject var pathState = PathState()
  var body: some View {
    NavigationStack(path: $pathState.path) {
      Image(systemName: "figure.fall")
        .imageScale(.large)
        .foregroundStyle(.tint)
        .navigationDestination(for: PathState.Destination.self) { destination in
          switch destination {
          case .first:
            FirstView()
          case .second:
            SecondView()
          case .third:
            ThirdView()
          }
        }
      NavigationLink("Go to FirstView", value: PathState.Destination.first)
    }
    .padding()
    .overlay(alignment: .top) {
      Text("Navigation Path: \(pathState.path.map(\.rawValue).debugDescription)")
    }
    .environmentObject(pathState)
  }
}

//------------------FirstView------------------
struct FirstView: View {
  var body: some View {
    NavigationLink("Go to SecondView", value: PathState.Destination.second)
  }
}

//-----------------SecondView------------------
struct SecondView: View {
  var body: some View {
    NavigationLink("Go to ThirdView", value: PathState.Destination.third)
  }
}

//------------------ThirdView------------------
struct ThirdView: View {
  @EnvironmentObject var pathState: PathState
  var body: some View {
    Text("RootPath: \(pathState.path.count)")
    Button(action: {
      pathState.path = [] // take everything off the navigation stack
    }, label: {
      Text("Go to ContentView")
    })
  }
}
```

More info about navigationDestination:

As you make new navigation screens add them to the enum. If you want to define them all up front, you can just add a default to the switch to catch the cases where the view hasn't been built yet, like `default: Text("Under Construction")`.

Now, you don't need to use a custom enum for the path value or make a `PathState` object at all, that is just one way to organize things and makes sense for this example. The navigationDestination just needs to return some `view` for a given navigation `value` that is being pushed. It can always be the same general view. Like:

```
.navigationDestination { screenNumber in
  ScreenView(number: screenNumber)
}

struct ScreenView: View {
  let number: Int 
  var body: some View { Text("This is screen \(number)") }
}
```

or just ignore the value and use some other logic.

```
.navigationDestination { _ in
   if Calendar.autoupdating.isDateInWeekend(.now) {
     return WeekendView()
   } else {
     return WeekdayView()
   }
}
```

Comment: Okay, that's clear. I'm just asking if we're obliged to anticipate all the views from the start of the design or if there's a more flexible way of doing it with generic views or if it's mandatory to make some kind of router? Also, why when I put **.navigationBarBackButtonHidden()** on a **navigationLink** does it hide the button for the current view and not for the destination?

Comment: Added more detail to the answer, if you've used Navigation with UIKit or NavigationView, this is way more flexible, but that means you need to think about how to organize your app a bit more.
As for the hiding back button, add that modifier to the view being presented.

Answer (score 0):

For dynamic routes you can create a custom environment value and use it in the views. Some part of the code is shown below:

```
enum Route: Hashable {
    case home
    case login
    case detail(Product)
}

struct NavigateAction {
    typealias Action = (NavigationType) -> ()
    let action: Action
    func callAsFunction(_ navigationType: NavigationType) {
        action(navigationType)
    }
}

enum NavigationType: Hashable {
    case push(Route)
    case unwind(Route)
}

struct NavigateEnvironmentKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static var defaultValue: NavigateAction = NavigateAction(action: { _ in })
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var navigate: (NavigateAction) {
        get { self[NavigateEnvironmentKey.self] }
        set { self[NavigateEnvironmentKey.self] = newValue }
    }
}
```

The environment value can be used as follows:

```
struct ReviewList: View {
    
    @Environment(\.navigate) private var navigate
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Reviews")
            Button("Go to Product") {
                 navigate(.push(.detail(Product(name: "Chair"))))
            }
            Button("Go back to Home View") {
                navigate(.unwind(.home))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For more details, check out the following section of the article:
https://azamsharp.com/2023/02/28/building-large-scale-apps-swiftui.html#navigation